# SOLVED: Why am I getting a message saying I have a missing value when both values have been explicitly defined?

Tags: r, function, loops, while-loop

I would love if someone could help me out with trying to figure out why my function is not working. Despite defining "b" as an input to the function and "upper" within the function, I am receiving the following error message:

"Error in while (b < upper) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Here is the code for my function and the input I am trying to use:

```
## Require package "DescTools" for CorCI() function and install if not installed
if (!require('DescTools')) install.packages('DescTools'); library('DescTools')

my.function <- function(a, b, c = .8, d = .9){
  n <- 2 ## Set counter at 2 
  upper <- 1 ## Set initial upper value to 1 so it will be greater than b
    while (b < upper) {
      n <- n + 1
      CI1 <- CorCI(rho = a, n = n, conf.level = d, alternative = "two.sided")
      CI2 <- CorCI(rho = unname(CI1[3]), n = n, conf.level = c, alternative = "less")
      upper <- unname(CI2[3])
    }
  print(n)
}

my.function(a = -.5, b = -.3)
```

I've tried a bunch of different solutions and nothing has seemed to work. I replaced the while loop with a repeat and break loop, and that didn't help. The strange thing is, I have another function that is very similar but just switches the directions of a few things (and the input is different as well, as the functions serve slightly different tasks), and it works just fine. Here is the function that does work:

```
## Require package "DescTools" for CorCI() function and install if not installed
if (!require('DescTools')) install.packages('DescTools'); library('DescTools')

my.function2 <- function(a, b, c = .8, d = .9){
  n <- 2 ## start n counter at 2
  lower <- -1 ## Set initial lower value to -1 so it will be less than b
    while (b > lower) {
      n <- n + 1
      CI1 <- CorCI(rho = a, n = n, conf.level = d, alternative = "two.sided")
      CI2 <- CorCI(rho = unname(CI1[2]), n = n, conf.level = c, alternative = "greater")
      lower <- unname(CI2[2])
    }
print(n)
}

my.function2(a = .5, b = .3)
```

The two functions seem like they should be equivalent, so I don't know why one works and the other does not. Any insight you could provide would be super helpful! Thanks!

-Adam

Comment: Your while loop fail because `unname(CI2[3])` returns an `NaN` value

Comment: Instead of editing the post to include the solution it is better if you post it below in the answer section. You can answer your own question.

Comment: Thanks, @RonakShah! I didn't know that was an option. I just added that.

Comment: and thanks @MohanGovindasamy for your comment, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Based on a helpful comment from Mohan Govindasamy, who pointed out that unname(CI2[3]) was returning a NaN, I looked closer into the Cor CI code, and realized that when N was set to 3 (the initial 2 + 1), CorCI returned a NaN for the confidence interval because there was not enough values. So I simply changed the initial counter to n <- 5 instead of n <- 2 and this solved the problem! Thanks, Mohan!

Working code:

```
## Require package "DescTools" for CorCI() function and install if not installed
if (!require('DescTools')) install.packages('DescTools'); library('DescTools')

my.function <- function(a, b, c = .8, d = .9){
  n <- 5 ## Set counter at 5 instead of 2 
  upper <- 1 ## Set initial upper value to 1 so it will be greater than b
    while (b < upper) {
      n <- n + 1
      CI1 <- CorCI(rho = a, n = n, conf.level = d, alternative = "two.sided")
      CI2 <- CorCI(rho = unname(CI1[3]), n = n, conf.level = c, alternative = "less")
      upper <- unname(CI2[3])
    }
  print(n)
}

my.function(a = -.5, b = -.3)
```